# Using jQuery to remove parent.parent HTML div?

Tags: jquery

Using jQUery, how can I handle removing the parent of a parent? My current PHP only removes the parent div, which just removes the "remove button" itself and not the included input box.

PHP:

```
        $( document ).ready(function() {
            var max_fields = 10; //maximum input boxes allowed
            var wrapper = $(".input_fields_wrap"); //Fields wrapper
            var add_button = $(".add_field_button"); //Add button ID

            $(wrapper).on("click",".remove_field", function(e){ //user click on remove text
                e.preventDefault(); $(this).parent('div').remove(); x--;
            })
        });
```

HTML:

```
            <div class="row subrow">
                <div class="form-group col-lg-8">
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <span class="input-group-addon">Event Name</span>
                        <input type='text' class='form-control input-sm' name="mytext[]">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-4"><a href="#" class="remove_field">Remove</a></div>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you will always have the parent of the parent have a class row, you can use [closest](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) to traverse up the tree to match the parent element and remove.

```
$(wrapper).on("click",".remove_field", function(e){ //user click on remove text
    e.preventDefault(); 
    $(this).closest(".row").remove(); 
    x--;
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace this :

```
$(this).parent('div').remove();
```

With this :

```
$(this).parent().parent().remove();
```

Comment: This works, thank you! I do like the other answer a little more, but this definitely got the job done. :)